# iOS - UI Automation get textfield by accessibility label?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, ios-ui-automation

So in my nib file i enabled accessibility and set the accessibility label of a textfield to "txt"
I am trying to find this textfiled based on accessibility name and change its text.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var application = target.frontMostApp(); 
var mainWindow = application.mainWindow();
mainWindow.logElementTree();

// This works
var textField = mainWindow.textFields()[0];

//this doesn't work
var textField = mainWindow.textFields()["txt"];

textField.setValue("Hello");
```

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I find a label based on accessibility label?

**EDIT:**

I am open to other solutions as well, I am trying to avoid getting the textfield based on the index

Comment: What your logElementTree shows for this texfield name?

Comment: It works fine after setting the accessibilityLebel in the code. But why it doesn't work when it is set in the Interface Builder? Could u give any details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar problem and setting the accessibility label value in the code instead in the nib file solve my problem. For example, I have a UITextField that I need to access in my UIAutomation script, I would have to set the accessibility label value in the viewDidLoad method as shown below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    testTxtField.accessibilityLabel = @"myTxtBox";
}
```

and below is my UIAutomation Script

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var application = target.frontMostApp(); 
var mainWindow = application.mainWindow();
mainWindow.logElementTree();

// This works
//var textField = mainWindow.textFields()[0];

// Now, this work too.
var textField = mainWindow.textFields()["myTxtBox"];
textField.setValue("Hello");

UIALogger.logMessage("Text field:" + textField.label());
```